# Data disappears from datagridviewcomboboxes when I select value in another row

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

I am using multiple datagridviewcomboboxes in a datagridview row. 
They include shift, position, and 7 others for a name for each day.
They are populated from field in a database like this:

```
Private Sub Populate_DGV_ComboBoxes()
    Dim ShiftCmd As SqlCommand
    Dim ShiftSQL As String
    Dim ShiftConn As New SqlConnection()
    If GlobalVariables.logProd = 1 Then
        GlobalVariables.strConnection = "CCAPProdConnectionString"
    Else
        GlobalVariables.strConnection = "CCAPTestConnectionString"
    End If
    ShiftConn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings(GlobalVariables.strConnection).ConnectionString
    Try
        ShiftConn.Open()
        Dim i As Integer = 0
        For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dgvCreateSchedule.Rows
            Dim ShiftName As New DataGridViewComboBoxCell
            With ShiftName
                Dim Shiftadapter As New SqlDataAdapter
                Dim ShiftDT As New DataTable
                'Dim val As String = dr.Cells("Shift Name").Value.ToString
                ShiftSQL = "select ShiftName from shifts where RecordActive = 1 order by ShiftName"
                ShiftCmd = New SqlCommand(ShiftSQL, ShiftConn)
                Using ShiftCmd
                    Shiftadapter.SelectCommand = ShiftCmd
                    Shiftadapter.Fill(ShiftDT)
                End Using
                .DataSource = ShiftDT
                .ValueMember = "ShiftName"
                .DisplayMember = "ShiftName"
                dgvCreateSchedule.Rows(i).Cells("ShiftName") = ShiftName
                i = i + 1
            End With
        Next
        ShiftConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        'MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try
```

I select all the values I want and then go to the next new row.
As soon as I select a value from a combobox on the new row ALL of the values disappear from the previous row.
Why is this happening and how do i stop it?

Comment: From which event are you running this routine?

Comment: For some reason I was never notified that a comment was added. Sorry. I run it from a button that unhides the panel that contains the grid

Comment: OK. I actually had it in 2 places. I had also added the following code

    Private Sub dgvCreateSchedule_RowsAdded() Handles dgvCreateSchedule.RowsAdded
        Populate_DGV_ComboBoxes()
    End Sub

And evidently this is the cause of my issue. Because if I remove that code then it stops deleting the previous row of data.

However, when new rows are added to the grid the dropdown boxes do not get populated.
So then what is the proper way to populate datagridview dropdowns so that each new row contains the choices?

Comment: Personally I would remove the Try/Catch block as you're hiding any exceptions that maybe occurring (if any) Also I would use DataGridViewComboBoxColumn and not adding Cells as you are. If you want to continue as such maybe work with the current row and not iterate all rows like this: {For Each dr As DataGridViewRow In dgvCreateSchedule.Rows} just do your changes on the CurrentRow instead. And for that to be replacing row values suggests your routine is running an a different event than Button Click

Comment: Gotcha.. What you want to do is create a DataTable with your shifts, this could be done on FormLoad and doesnt really need to be part of this routine, the datasource just needs to be available. Then create a DataGridViewComboColumn, not Cell. Set the DataSource of this column to the Shift DataTable. You may also want to set AutoGenerateColumns to false on the DGV and add all the Cols manually, be sure to set all the DataPropertyName to your column names, and the DisplayMember and ValueMember of your DataGridViewComboBox

Comment: What I discovered is that since my code was going through each row and repopulating the dropdown boxes when each new row was added that this was causing the issue. So I created two separate routines - one for populating the existing rows and another for populating only a new row when added. This seems to have fixed the issue.